# jquery validation: one message for group of required fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I've the following markup:

```
<input name="input1" required>
<input name="input2" required>
<input name="input3" required>
<input name="input4" required>
....
<input type="checkbox name="check1">
<input type="checkbox name="check2">
...
<div id="errorPlacement"></div>
```

After pressing submit, I want to highlight the empty inputs, and show the following messages in the errorPlacement div only once if it necessary:

One for that case when some input is empty

```
You have to answer all the questions
```

One for that case when some checkbox not checked

```
You have to check all the checkboxes
```

The promlem is that I get the messages more times according to the number of empty inputs. Please help me remove duplicates from the errorPlacement.

Default "required" generates the messages more times.
I tried "groups", but no success.
"require_from_group" generated several messages too for me.

I have a not working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AcGL3/

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: How did you try `groups` with no success? Because the `groups` option is exactly how you'd do it.  And if you'd read the docs, you'd see that `require_from_group` method has nothing to do with what you're asking.

Comment: You should put the code in your OP rather than rely on the jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `groups` option works fine:  http://jsfiddle.net/AcGL3/3/

```
groups: {
    inputGroup: "input1 input2 input3 input4",
    checkboxGroup: "check1 check2",            
},
```

Using the `errorPlacement` function to improperly put the messages into a central container is what breaks it.

Looking at the docs, there is something called [the `errorLabelContainer` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorlabelcontainer)...

```
errorLabelContainer: "#errorPlacement",
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/AcGL3/4/**